# Existence of function satisfying $f(f'(x))=x$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, derivatives, functional-equations

**My project is to Study the existence of a continuous function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable almost everywhere satisfying $  f\circ f'(x)=x$ almost everywhere $x \in \mathbb{R}$**

I began the study by supposing $f\in   C ^ 1(\mathbb{R}) $, I have shown that f does not exist.

After, I found some difficulties when we assume only f differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, I had an answer using Darboux's theorem [Questions about the existence of a function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312572/questions-about-the-existence-of-a-function?noredirect=1#comment6815760_3312572).

Now, I want to attack the initial problem. Previous arguments do not work!

Do you have any suggestions for me?

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Can u explain me why u voted against this question?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  
in the above link,  I explained this case   thank you for saving my question.

Comment: The question is not yet solved in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/337607/existence-of-function-satisfying-ffx-x-almost-everywhere

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio  
the link https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312572/questions-about-the-existence-of-a-function?noredirect=1#comment6815760_3312572  does not answer the question you asked me?

Comment: Convert your equation into a differential equation and seek out for a solution

Comment: @ ibnAbu can explain your approach ?!